# How make cursor doesn't go in new line when i press Enter in TextArea (in GWT)?

Tags: gwt, textarea, newline

I tried method textArea.setCursorPos(0) but it didn't work.
May be it is posiible to resolve by Java Script but i don't know((

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you can use `return false;` or  `event.returnValue = false;` (IE), event.preventDefault(); (FF, Chromium, Opera) in event handler.

With GWT you just use the [NativeEvent](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent.html)'s preventDefault() method

```
area.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
    if (event.getCharCode() == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```